# PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSignal object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, pyqt4

I'm having issues with a custom signal in a class I made.

Relevant code:

```
self.parse_triggered = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

def parseFile(self):
    self.emit(self.parse_triggered)
```

Both of those belong to the class: RefreshWidget.
In its parent class I have:

```
self.refreshWidget.parse_triggered.connect(self.tabWidget.giveTabsData())
```

When I try to run the program, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self.tabWidget.giveTabsData()` looks suspect as it would need to return a function / handler, but that shouldn't be related to the actual error you're getting. Otherwise, it looks good.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. If you find a resolution, could you post and edit with what the problem was?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I had the same exact problem as you.

Try moving

```
self.parse_triggered = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

out of your constructor but inside your class declaration. So instead of it looking like this:

```
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parse_triggered = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
```

It should look like this:

```
class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    parse_triggered = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)
```

This might not be at all what you are looking for, but it worked for me. I switched back to old-style signals anyways because I haven't found a way in new-style signals to have an undefined number or type of parameters.

Comment: Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: This has a problem. The signal will be shared between each instance.

Comment: The reason that this works is due to the way the PyQt library has internally implemented `pyqtSignal`. Specifically, under [Support for Signals and Slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) we find that the library distinguishes between unbound and bound signals. The magic is performed as follows: "A signal (specifically an unbound signal) is an attribute of a class that is a sub-class of `QObject`. When a signal is referenced as an attribute of an instance of the class then PyQt5 automatically binds the instance to the signal in order to create a bound signal."

Comment: One more note, the superclass must be initialised as well. I was missing that call in the subclass __init__() function assuming it would be done automatically and that caused the same error message regarding signals.

Comment: Is there a way to get around this, if the class was already defined through Qt Creator, heavily layouted and dynamically translated with pyuic, or do I have to subclass it myself manually to enable to signal like `parse_triggered`?

Comment: More info on this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425316/how-to-create-pyqt-properties-dynamically

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15033578/7919597) answer explains why the signal is not shared between instances as @ken-kinder stated above: the class attribute is of type `<unbound PYQT_SIGNAL QString)>` while the instance attribute is of type `<bound PYQT_SIGNAL event>`

Comment: It's important to realize here that you do NOT use the class variable signal to connect a signal listener (this signal is unbound), but rather the instance signal variable of the class which PyQt creates for you under the hood.

Answer (score 79):

You also get that error message if you fail to call `super()` or `QObject.__init__()` in your custom class.

A checklist for defining custom signals in a class in Qt in Python:

- your class derives from QObject (directly or indirectly)
- your class `__init__` calls `super()` (or calls `QObject.__init__()` directly.)
- your signal is defined as a class variable, not an instance variable
- the signature (formal arguments) of your signal matches the signature of any slot that you will connect to the signal e.g. `()` or `(int)` or `(str)` or `((int,), (str,))`

Comment: The error I got here was along the lines of "signals must be bound to QObject instances, not <myclass>". Since I had derived from QObject, I found this baffling. But I hadn't called the QObject `__init__` in any way. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Since I was using a QRunnable, I also had this problem since it does not inherit QObject. The solution was to make my class a subclass of QObject and also QRunnable, and call both `QObject.__init__(self)` and `QRunnable.__init__(self)` in my class' `__init__` method.

Comment: This is extremely important to remember! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I have recently started working with PySide (Nokia's own version of PyQt), and saw the exact same behaviour (and solution) with custom new-style signals. My biggest concern with the solution was that using a class variable to hold the signal would mess things up when I have multiple instances of that class (QThreads in my case).

From what I could see, `QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)` finds the Signal variable in the class and creates a copy of that Signal for the instance. I have no idea what `QObject.__init__()` does, but the resulting Signal does proper `connect()`, `disconnect()` and `emit()` methods (and also a `__getitem__()` method), whereas the class Signal or standalone Signal variables created outside of a QObject-derived class do not have these methods and can't be used properly.

Answer (score 7):

To use the signal/slot system you need to have a QObject inherited class.

Here is a simple example:

```
    from PySide import QtCore
    class LivingBeing(QtCore.QObject):
      bornSignal = QtCore.Signal() # initialise our signal

      def __init__(self,name):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self) # initialisation required for object inheritance
        self.bornSignal.connect(self.helloWorld) # connect the born signal to the helloworld function
        self.name = name #
        self.alive = False

      def summonFromClay(self):
        self.alive = True
        self.bornSignal.emit() # emit the signal

      def helloWorld(self):
         print "Hello World !, my name is %s, this place is so great !" % self.name

    # now try the little piece of code
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      firstHuman = LivingBeing('Adam')
      firstHuman.summonFromClay()
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.
I forgot that if a class uses Signals, then it must inherit from QObject. I was doing some re-factoring and did not pay attention to this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you connect directly to the signal, while you can do
`self.connect(widget, SIGNAL('parse_triggered()'), listener.listening_method)`?

where self is, for example, the form itself, and may be the same as listener

Comment: Supposedly that is the "old way" of doing connect(). From what I've read, that method won't put up any errors even if they exist.

Comment: This is old-style signals and slots. Both work, but people tend to think the new-style is more elegant/pythonic.