# Why does PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal have to be initialized as a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

By trial and error I have figured out that one has to initialize pyqtSignal outside __init()__ call like this:

```
class BackgroundService(QObject):
    file_updated = pyqtSignal(name='file_updated')
    def __init__(self, slot_method):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_updated.connect(slot_method)
```

Otherwise if I do like this

```
class BackgroundService(QObject):
    def __init__(self, slot_method):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_updated = pyqtSignal(name='file_updated')
        self.file_updated.connect(slot_method)
```

I get an error `AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'`

Why does the signal have to be initialized outside the constructor?

Comment: I've asked this also before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025686/why-does-pyside-implicitely-create-object-members-from-class-members-for-signals)