# Make QSpinBox.valueChanged() only respond to Mouse Wheel

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I have QSpinBox's Signal `valueChanged` connected to a QWidget's function like:

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        #just an example
        mySpinBox = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        mySpinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.foo)

   def foo(self):
       if value was changed by Mouse Wheel:
            #do this
       else:
            #do nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Gombat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066891/gombat) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970312/pyqt4-qtcore-pyqtsignal-object-has-no-attribute-connect) question (because how it is explained in provided tutorial it wil raise an error) i did this in the widget

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    mySignal1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal() #these have to be here or... 
    mySignal2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal() #...there will be an attribute error

    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        #just an example
        self.mySpinBox1 = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.mySpinBox2 = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.mySpinBox1.installEventFilter(self)
        self.mySpinBox2.installEventFilter(self)
        self.mySignal1.connect(self.foo)
        self.mySignal2.connect(self.bar)

   def eventFilter(self, source, event):
       if source is self.spinBox1:
           if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel:
                self.spinBox1.wheelEvent(event)
                self.mySignal1.emit()
           return True
       else:
           return False
    elif source is self.spinBox2:
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Wheel:
            self.spinBox2.wheelEvent(event)
            self.mySignal2.emit()
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

    def foo(self):
        #right here, when a mouse wheel event occured in spinbox1

    def bar(self):
        #right here, when a mouse wheel event occured in spinbox2
```

hope this helps. thanks (untested, because it is just an example, there might be errors)

Answer (score 1):

Derive QSpinBox and override the wheelevent

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#wheelEvent

You can define your own signal which will be emitted by the wheelevent to obtain the behavior you want to have.

For an example / tutorial, see:
http://pythoncentral.io/pysidepyqt-tutorial-creating-your-own-signals-and-slots/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give an example on how to create a Qt Signal? Cause so far i've only used default Signals/Slots.

Comment: I appended a link to a tutorial in my answer.

Comment: Deriving is one way, another way is to install an event filter. Qt's event filtration system has been designed specifically so that altering class behavior is easier without having to subclass.

Comment: actually i did both. i will provide an answer to that