# How to modularize property creation in PySide

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I am largely following the instructions [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_UsingQtProperties) for using properties and I could just use the Person object given there as the backend, but that is not very useful. I am trying to figure out how to do the following two things:

1. Use multiple instances of multiple such classes in a backend and connect them in a way that PySide/QML doesn't complain
2. Allow customization of the backend by modules to be determined at runtime (i.e. I eventually want to componentize the application - have different components implementing an interface, the component contributes separately to both the GUI and the backend; but this question concerns only the backend)

This is in contrast to simply defining all of these Properties along with their setter and getter on the main backend class (which I was able to do), which is what I mean by modularize in the question.

I modify the Person example from the link to make it something the UI can change and give it an extra attribute for kicks...

*person.py*

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal, Property

class Person(QObject):

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._name = name
        self._age = age

    def getName(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, name):
        print(f"Setting name to {name}")
        self._name = name

    def getAge(self):
        return self._age

    def setAge(self, age):
        print(f"Setting age to {age}")
        self._age = age

    @Signal
    def name_changed(self):
        pass

    @Signal
    def age_changed(self):
        pass

    name = Property(str, getName, setName, notify=name_changed)
    age = Property(str, getAge, setAge, notify=age_changed)
```

Just as an example I'll create two instances of Person. The first instance I have created as a class member. This is not really what I want, but closer resembles the way properties were used in the link. The second instance is what I really want which is that the properties are instance members, so that I can add them from elsewhere in the application at runtime. Neither method currently works

*main.py*

```
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Property, Signal
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from person import Person

class Backend(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    def registerProperty(self, name : str, prop):
        setattr(self, name, prop)

    person1 = Person("Jill", 29)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    context = engine.rootContext()

    # Instance of the Python object
    backend = Backend()

    # simulate properties added by another module
    backend.registerProperty("person2", Person("Jack", 30))

    qmlFile = join(dirname(__file__), 'view3.qml')
    engine.load(abspath(qmlFile))

    # Expose the Python object to QML
    context.setContextProperty("backend", backend)

    # I tried this but it did nothing
    # context.setContextProperty("backend.jack", backend.jack)
    # context.setContextProperty("backend.jill", backend.jill)

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

finally the *view3.qml* file is simply

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

ApplicationWindow {

    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        TextField {
            implicitWidth: 200
            onAccepted: {
                backend.person1.name = text
            }
        }
        TextField {
            implicitWidth: 200
            onAccepted: {
                backend.person1.age = text
            }
        }
        TextField {
            implicitWidth: 200
            onAccepted: {
                backend.person2.name = text
            }
        }
        TextField {
            implicitWidth: 200
            onAccepted: {
                backend.person2.age = text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to set any of the values in the UI the error is always the same (the error appears against the QML file)

```
TypeError: Value is undefined and could not be converted to an object
```

Ultimately I would like to have such objects nested to any arbitrary depth. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here? Or am I maybe completely off track with the way I'm setting about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I'm qualified to advise you on overall architecture design for GUI apps, but I think I can explain what's going wrong, and suggest a way to do what you describe. Your `registerProperty` method adds a Python attribute, but as you've seen, that doesn't make it visible from QML.

**The bad news:** Qt properties cannot be added to an object after it's created.
**The good news:** You can create a Qt property that's a list (or a dictionary), and add to it.

One pitfall to be aware of is that to expose a list to QML, you specify its type as `'QVariantList'`. (For dictionaries, use `'QVariantMap'`, and make sure your keys are strings.)

Here's an example of how your Backend class could look. (Using `super()` to access the parent class means you don't have to pass `self` to its initializer.)

```py
from Pyside2.QtCore import QObject, Property, Signal

class Backend(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.people = []
    
    people_changed = Signal('QVariantList')

    @Property('QVariantList', notify=people_changed)
    def people(self):
        return self._people

    @value.setter
    def people(self, new_people):
        self._people = new_people
        self.people_changed.emit(new_people)

    def add_person(self, name, age):
        self.people.append(Person(name, age, self))
        # Note: only ASSIGNING will automatically fire the changed
        # signal. If you append, you have to fire it yourself.
        self.people_changed.emit(self.people)
```

This will keep QML up to date as you add people; you could also create a similar method to remove people. Parenting each person to the Backend object makes sure Qt will keep references to them as long as your Backend still exists.

For a truly dynamic collection of properties, perhaps you could give your top-level Backend object a dictionary that your other components add to. So `backend.people` would become `backend.properties['people']`, and a specific module would be responsible for adding that key to the `properties` dictionary, then adding to and removing entries from it.

---

Specifying all those getters and setters is a hassle, isn't it? I spent so long feeling like there must be a better way, and only recently came across a solution here on Stack Overflow. Using [this metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66266877/12975140), your Person class and the Backend I posted above could be simplified to:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject

# Assuming you save the linked code as properties.py:
from properties import PropertyMeta, Property

class Person(QObject, metaclass=PropertyMeta):
    name = Property(str)
    age = Property(int)
    
    def __init__(self, name, age, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class Backend(QObject, metaclass=PropertyMeta):
    people = Property(list)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.people = []

    def add_person(self, name, age):
        self.people.append(Person(name, age, self))
        # Automatically emits changed signal, even for in-place changes
```

(I also changed `age` to an `int`, but it could still be a `str` if you need it to be.)